# postgresql blocking behavior

Tags: postgresql

I would like to understand the blocking behavior of postgresql. Consider I have an insert statement starting at 1:00 (stage A) completed at 2:00 (stage B).

However, I have a few complex select statements:

```
S1, starting at 0:30, completed at 1:30
S2, starting at 0:30, completed at 2:30
S3, starting at 1:30, completed at 2:30
S4, starting at 1:30, completed at 1:45,
```

What would be the associated end result I shall get? From one test I had myself, I realize
S1, S4 -> stage A.

How about S2 and S3?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the answer, S1->S4 are all associated with stage A.

A more complex follow up question.

Imagine I have a view based on the db,

```
Create view db_view1 as select a+random() as a from db
```

The insert (I1) statement is

```
insert into db select * from db_view1
```

Again, I1 starting at 1:00 (stage A) completed at 2:00 (stage B). However, another client implement the same insert. 4 scenario below:

```
S5, apply another I1 starting at 0:30, completed at 1:30
S6, apply another I1 starting at 0:30, completed at 2:30
S7, apply another I1 starting at 1:30, completed at 2:30
S8, apply another I1 starting at 1:30, completed at 1:45,
```

For S5-S8, what happen in each of the scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By virtue of PostgreSQL's multi-versioning implementation, no transaction will be blocked. Each of these queries will see the state of the database like it was before the insert started.

PostgreSQL takes a *snapshot* of the database at the start of the query, and it sees the data as they were when the query started. Also, you never see modifications from a transaction that was not yet completed when the query started.

Comment: Thanks! So S1-S4 are all for Stage A. How about db dependent insert? I will elaborate more in a edit

Comment: No, ask a new question.

Comment: I see. I have posted my question here, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301463/postgresql-blocking-behavior-for-table-dependent-insert, could you help with that? Thanks so much again.