# postgresql blocking behavior for table dependent insert

Tags: postgresql

This question follows up the previous simpler question: [postgresql blocking behavior](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301435/postgresql-blocking-behavior)

Old context:

I would like to understand the blocking behavior of postgresql. Consider I have an insert statement starting at 1:00 (stage A) completed at 2:00 (stage B).

However, I have a few complex select statements:

```
S1, starting at 0:30, completed at 1:30
S2, starting at 0:30, completed at 2:30
S3, starting at 1:30, completed at 2:30
S4, starting at 1:30, completed at 1:45,
```

What would be the associated end result I shall get? From one test I had myself, I realize
S1, S4 -> stage A.

How about S2 and S3?

**Answer:**

Thanks for the answer, S1->S4 are all associated with stage A.

**Follow up:**

A more complex follow up question.

Imagine I have a view based on the db,

```
Create view db_view1 as select a+random() as a from db
```

The insert (I1) statement is

```
insert into db select * from db_view1
```

Again, I1 starting at 1:00 (stage A) completed at 2:00 (stage B). However, another client implement the same insert. 4 scenario below:

```
S5, apply another I1 starting at 0:30, completed at 1:30
S6, apply another I1 starting at 0:30, completed at 2:30
S7, apply another I1 starting at 1:30, completed at 2:30
S8, apply another I1 starting at 1:30, completed at 1:45,
```

For S5-S8, what happen in each of the scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result will always be the same: `db` will have all rows from `db_view1` at stage A added twice.

The `SELECT` that is part of the `INSERT` will see stage A, just like the query in the other question.

Comment: This is quite mind blowing for me.  I always thought there is some hidden internal order (sequence of statement) there. For example if originally the table had 5 rows, I thought it will have 5+5+10 rows in the end. But from what you said, I will only get 5+5+5 rows in the end. Very mind blowing and thank you very much!